# Hide all code when exporting notebook in Jupyter Lab to PDF

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When I export a notebook to PDF in jupyter lab i cannot hide the code cells in the output.
(Like 'View > Collapse All Code')

Is there a built in functionality to hide code in the output PDF?
For example by using the cell Metadata?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

`jupyter nbconvert path/to/your/ipynb --to=pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True`

Comment: Docs for nbconvert strangely aren't the first thing to pop up when searching for excluding different parts of the output, but they talk about this in their docs here:
https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html

Comment: I like @wspurgin approach because it is a one time setting in a .py file, then all the export are gonna be as you want. You just should search for "jupyter_nbconvert_config.py" and add `c.TemplateExporter.exclude_input = True` to it.